# M2E Cron jobs not automatically running in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, m2eclipse

we have the above problem since this August when using M1 then migrated to M2 in Sept after our hosting company upgraded their server in early August

Could anyone help us on this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `bin/magento cron:install`?

Also, check out `bin/magento list` to see a list of possible commands.